# AJAX won't parse JSON into a loop in order to create articles

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm using an Ajax call to load articles on a page as a replacement of a database, however I can't seem to figure out how to loop this specific json file into usable articles on my page. The data either returns "undefined" or it returns an error parsing the JSON. This is the lastest Ajax call with a loop I've tried to implement:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "php/data.json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          'offset': 0,
          'limit': Papery.loadAmount
    },
        success: function(records){
            $.each(records, function(record){
                 $('.articlesFade').append('<article class="column"> <h1 class="headline">' + record.title +'</h1><h2 class="headline">'+ record.title_small +'</h2><p>'+ record.article_small +'</p><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/01/00/56/news-1172463_960_720.jpg"></article>').hide().fadeIn(1000);
             });
        }
    });
```

The article is supposed to appear in the "articles" div (along with the h1's etc.)

My JSON is structurure this way:

```
var json = [
   {
      "art_id":"1",
      "title":"Bicymple campagne",
      "title_small":"Bicymple everything changes.",
      "article":"Voor het vak \"visuele communicatie\" kregen we de opdracht om een aantal opmerkelijke of rare producten te promoten. Ik en mijn groep kregen het product \"Bicymple\".\r\n\r\n<br><br>\r\nDe Bicymple is een fiets die gebruikt kan voor het los besturen van voor- en achterwiel worden om makkelijk te navigeren door steden, maar ook om stunts op uit te voeren. Als groep was aan ons om een doelgroep, kernwaarden en een aantal unique selling points te koppelen aan de fiets om een campagne te vormen.\r\n\r\n<br><br>\r\nHet eindproduct was een campagne genaamd: \"Bicymple. Everything changes\". Het idee achter de campagne is dat het design van de doorsnee fiets iedere eeuw veranderd, dus deze eeuw vind er weer een verandering plaats: de Bicymple. Dit werd tot uiting gebracht in posters, een landingspage en een moodvideo.\r\n\r\n<br><br>\r\nOp een zelfgemaakte landingspage plaatste we een moodvideo ter ondersteuning van onze campagne. Op de landingspage kon je het thema van de pagina en de muziek onder de moodvideo veranderen door op de verschillende fietsdesigns door de eeuwen heen te klikken. Het was technisch niet van hoge kwaliteit door de middelmatige HTML\/CSS kennis destijds, maar het concept kwam duidelijk over.\r\n\r\n<br><br>\r\nDeze groepsopdracht leerde ik om visuele middelen in te zetten om een product te promoten met een stukje strategie. Onze inspanning werd beloont met een 8.",
      "article_small":"Een schoolopdracht voor het vak visuele communicatie, waar het promoten en re-branden van het product \"Bicymple\" centraal stond. In groepsverband cre&euml;erde we een concept en werkte dit uit tot visuele uitingen.",
      "created_article":"2016-05-24 11:23:21",
      "image_article":"__poster3.jpg,__poster2.jpg,__poster1.jpg,bicymple_landingspage.jpg,bicymple.png",
      "youtube":null
   },
   {
      "art_id":"2",
      "title":"Rascal Games",
      "title_small":"The game is in your hands",
      "article":"Rascal Games was mijn eerste project op Fontys ICT. Met alle kennis van de 4 richtingen (Technology, Media Design, Software Engineering & Business) moesten we in groepsverband een product verzinnen en maken. Met mijn groep hebben we een game genaamd: \"Platemania\" en een console genaamd: \"Digipult\" in het leven geroepen.\r\n<br><br>\r\nOnze groep bestond uit 5 leden die we verdeelde over de richtig die ze het leukste vonden of waar ze het beste in waren. Ik richtte me voornamelijk op Media Design taken zoals de website en promotiemateriaal. \r\n<br><br>\r\nIn de foto's hierboven zie je onze groep met de console en de game op de achtergrond. \r\n\r\n",
      "article_small":"Rascal Games was mijn eerste project op Fontys ICT. Met alle kennis van de 4 richtingen (Technology, Media Design, Software Engineering & Business) moesten we in groepsverband een product verzinnen en maken. Met mijn groep hebben we een game genaamd: \"Platemania\" en een console genaamd: \"Digipult\" in het leven geroepen.",
      "created_article":"2016-05-24 13:00:24",
      "image_article":"rascal_logo.jpg,rascalgroup.jpg,rascalwebsite.jpg,rascal.jpg,plate_mania.jpg,rascal.png",
      "youtube":null
   },
   {
      "art_id":"3",
      "title":"Computer van de toekomst: Vision",
      "title_small":"Een voice recognition AR prototype",
      "article":"Vision is een klein, maar toekomstgericht project voor het vak \"Experience Design\". Het doel van de opdracht was om met behulp van een Arduino en een visualisatie een toekomstbeeld te schetsen voor de computer van de toekomst.  \r\n<br><br>\r\nEen hoop variabelen kome kijken bij het designen van een product dat nog niet zal bestaan voor tenminste 10+ jaar. De grootste design challenge was het designen voor de \"lens\", want wij denken dat we allemaal een lens zullen gebruiken in de toekomst. Omdat een mens 2 ogen heeft en moeilijk kan focussen met iets op de lens moesten we goed nadenken over de applicatie van het product en waar informatie te displayen.\r\n<br><br>\r\nAls Mediadesigner hebben we niet geleerd hoe we om moeteb gaab met een Arduino en C, vandaar dat we gebruik hebben gemaakt van een Arduino library \"EasyVR\" om een voice recognition prototype te kunnen laten zien aan onze docenten samen met een visualisatie. Het prototype herkende de commando's \"Accept\" en \"Deny\" en liet hierbij een groen of rood lampje branden.\r\n<br><br>\r\nHet ging er bij dit project niet om om de beste visualisatie te maken, maar vooral om na te denken over de toekomst en buiten je comfort zone te stappen met een Arduino.\r\n",
      "article_small":"Vision is een klein, maar toekomstgericht project voor het vak \"Experience Design\". Het doel van de opdracht was om met behulp van een Arduino en een visualisatie een toekomstbeeld te schetsen voor de computer van de toekomst.  ",
      "created_article":"2016-05-27 15:49:54",
      "image_article":"stopmotion.jpg,arduinocode.jpg,arduino.jpg,vision.jpg,arduino_small.jpg",
      "youtube":"TV_pRT4fdE0"
   }
```

The article that I'm trying to loop is:

```
<article class="column">
    <h1 class="headline">TITLE</h1>
    <h2 class="headline">TITLE SMALL</h2>
    <p>'
        ARTICLE
    </p>
    <img src="IMAGE ARTICLE"> 
</article>
```

I'm hoping it's a small error I've overlooked, like it is most of the time, but this issue remains a problem in one of my functions for over 3 days now.

Comment: Why are you posting to a json file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the data.json file beginning with `var json = ...` as in your example? It should only contain the json data without JavaScript, so all in `{ ... }` in your case.
2. `$.ajax` supports a dataType called "json" that I would prefer to use in this case. So you do not have to do the JSON parsing manually and you will end up in the error handler on parsing errors.
3. `.html()` will *replace* all content, so I would suggest to use `.append()` instead
4. I think you want to do a `GET` instead of a `POST` request, but this should not matter in this case.

Comment: I edited the script with the points you included and a loop, now I get no errors, but nothing is appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the `dataType` be set to `json` as opposed to `text`?

I think the [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method would be more appropriate here:

```
$.getJSON("php/data.json", function( data ) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        $('.articles').html('<article class="column"> <h1 class="headline">'+ json[i].title +'</h1><h2 class="headline">'+ json[i].title_small +'</h2><p>'+ json[i].article_small +'</p></article>').hide().fadeIn(1000);
    };
});
```

What debugging steps have you tried? Is it even getting into the succcess handler?

Comment: I edited the code above to some suggestions, because I need the ajax call to be this way to pass some values. I've tried to alert after an "error" instead of success and you're right, it doesn't pass a succes. However, I have no clue why whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read data from JSON on server, then the operation is GET.
If you are expecting data type from server to be in JSON format, make the dataType as json